# Animate title in navigation bar

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm trying to animate titles in navigation bar. Like the one in this website:

http://www.danielspatzek.com/Home

What I tried is animating the hole word but it's not what I'm looking for:

```
<a>Contact</a>
a {
 letter-spacing: 1px;
  transition: all .1s ease-in;
} 
a:hover {
 letter-spacing: 0.2em;  
}
```

I know that I should apply the animation letter by letter but how can i make them spread out?

Thank you

Comment: post your trying

Comment: Please post your code here so we can see what you've tried already.

Comment: updated. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve it like this

```js
var spread = document.getElementsByClassName('spread');
[].forEach.call(spread, function(el) {
  // replace the content width divs
  el.innerHTML = '<span>' + el.innerText.split('').join('</span><span>') + '</span>'
  // custom :hover
  el.onmouseenter = function(e) {
    var childern = e.target.childNodes
    var width = e.target.offsetWidth / childern.length 
    for (var i = 0, child; child = childern[i]; i++) child.style.minWidth = width + 'px'
  }
  // remove custom style again
  el.onmouseleave = function(e) {
    var childern = e.target.childNodes
    for (var i = 0, child; child = childern[i]; i++) child.style.minWidth = '0'
  }
})
```

```css
.spread  {
  text-align:center;
}
.spread span {
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  text-align:center;
  min-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="spread">
  Title
</h1>
```

Comment: Works perfectly!! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The animation on give example has been implemented by a famous animation library **[Greensock](https://greensock.com/)**.

If you really want to build these kind of animations, make your hands a little bit dirty with its [Timelinelite](https://greensock.com/timelinelite) and [Tweenmax](https://greensock.com/tweenmax) classes.